# BigQuery command line tool - append to table using query

Tags: google-bigquery

Is it possible to append the results of running a query to a table using the bq command line tool? I can't see flags available to specify this, and when I run it it fails and states "table already exists"

```
bq query --allow_large_results --destination_table=project:DATASET.table "SELECT * FROM [project:DATASET.another_table]"
```

> BigQuery error in query operation: Error processing job '':
>   Already Exists: Table project:DATASET.table

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Originally BigQuery did not support the standard SQL idiom

```
 INSERT foo SELECT a,b,c from bar where d>0;
```

and you had to do it their way with `--append_table`

But according to @Will's answer, it works now.

Originally with bq, there was

`bq query --append_table ...`

The help for the bq query command is

```
$ bq query --help
```

And the output shows an append_table option in the top 25% of the output.

```
Python script for interacting with BigQuery.


USAGE: bq.py [--global_flags] <command> [--command_flags] [args]


query    Execute a query.

         Examples:
         bq query 'select count(*) from publicdata:samples.shakespeare'

         Usage:
         query <sql_query>

         Flags for query:

/home/paul/google-cloud-sdk/platform/bq/bq.py:
  --[no]allow_large_results: Enables larger destination table sizes.
  --[no]append_table: When a destination table is specified, whether or not to
    append.
    (default: 'false')
  --[no]batch: Whether to run the query in batch mode.
    (default: 'false')
  --destination_table: Name of destination table for query results.
    (default: '')
...
```

Instead of appending two tables together, you might be better off with a `UNION ALL` which is sql's version of concatenation.

In big query the comma or `,` operation between two tables as in `SELECT something from tableA, tableB` is a `UNION ALL`, NOT a `JOIN`, or at least it was the last time I looked.

Answer (score 6):

Just in case someone ends up finding this question in Google, BigQuery has evolved a lot since this post and now it does [support Standard](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/bq-command-line-tool).

If you want to append the results of a query to a table using the [DML syntax](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/dml-syntax) feature of the Standard version, you could do something like:

```
INSERT dataset.Warehouse (warehouse, state)
SELECT *
FROM UNNEST([('warehouse #1', 'WA'),
      ('warehouse #2', 'CA'),
      ('warehouse #3', 'WA')])
```

As presented in the [docs](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/dml-syntax#insert_examples).

For the command line tool it follows the same idea, you just need to add the flag `--use_legacy_sql=False`, like so:

```
bq query --use_legacy_sql=False "insert into dataset.table (field1, field2) select field1, field2 from table"
```

Answer (score 1):

According to the current documentation (March 2018): https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/loading-data-local#appending_to_or_overwriting_a_table_using_a_local_file

You should add:

`--noreplace` or `--replace=false`